# Is it possible to make Vim's completeopt appear at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: vim

It's really annoying to have it shift everything I'm doing down. I'd rather it pop up from the bottom. I've googled around a bit and haven't found a way to do this, or a plugin that would help.

Comment: Are you talking about the menu or the preview window?  If you are talking about the preview window, it respects splitbelow, iirc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preview window will respect the `splitbelow` setting.  Be aware that setting `splitbelow` will also affect your help window and how any new splits are displayed.